# While loop inside unit testing framework

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, cryengine

Looking at some macros of Qt Test Framework like `QCOMPARE`, this is the code:

```
#define QCOMPARE(actual, expected) \
do {\
    if (!QTest::qCompare(actual, expected, #actual, #expected, __FILE__, __LINE__))\
        return;\
} while (0)
```

As you can see, there is a while loop. I found the same thing inside CryEngine Unit Testing framework too. My question is simple: is there any reason to use that loop or maybe is something left there from an old implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll notice that the `while` condition is always false, so there is no actual loop. It's a common trick to have blocks in preprocessor macros and still require a semicolon at the end (so using the macro feels like using a function, and to not confuse some indenters). That is to say,

```
QCOMPARE(foo, bar); // <-- works
QCOMPARE(foo, bar)  // <-- will not work.
```

This is most useful in the context of `if` and `else`, where

```
if(something)
  QCOMPARE(foo, bar);
else
  do_something();
```

will expand to

```
if(something)
  do stuff() while(0);
else
  do_something();
```

which works, whereas a multiline macro with a block and without the loop construct would expand to

```
if(something)
  { stuff() }; // <-- if statement ends here
else           // <-- and this is at best a syntax error.
  do_something();
```

which does not.